# how to access to a method inside current namespace when using a compiled C# programmatically?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, code-generation

after reviewing all answers and question about compiling c# code programmatically, I choose this method:

**CompileCSCAtRuntime**

```
using System;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.CSharp;
using AA.UI.WPF.WND;

namespace AA.UI.WPF.COMMON
{
    public static class CompileCSCAtRuntime
    {
        public static void HelloWorld()
        {
            string code = @"
                using System;
                using System.Windows;
                using System.Windows.Forms;
                using System.Reflection;
                namespace AA.UI.WPF.COMMON
                {
                    public class Program
                    {
                        public static void Main()
                        {
                            var aassembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(@""Path_To_Assembly"");
                            Type CompileCSCAtRuntime = aassembly.GetType(""AA.UI.WPF.COMMON.CompileCSCAtRuntime"");
                            Type Login = aassembly.GetType(""AA.UI.WPF.WND.Login"");
                            MethodInfo AccessLogin = CompileCSCAtRuntime.GetMethod(""AccessLogin"");
                            dynamic L = AccessLogin.Invoke(null, null);
                            L.ShowMessage(""hi"");
                        }
                    }
                }
            ";
            CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
            CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters();
            string[] refr = {
                "System",
                "System.Windows",
                "System.Windows.Forms",
                "System.Drawing",
                "Microsoft.CSharp",
                "System.Core",
                "System.Data"};
            foreach (string r in refr)
                parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add($"{r}.dll");
            parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add($"Path_To_Assembly");
            parameters.GenerateInMemory = true;
            parameters.GenerateExecutable = true;
            CompilerResults results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, code);
            if (results.Errors.Count > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(
                    results.Errors
                        .Cast<CompilerError>()
                        .Select(error => error.ErrorText)
                        .Aggregate((s, s1) => s += $";\r\n\r\n{s1}"));
                return;
            }
            Assembly assembly = results.CompiledAssembly;
            Type program = assembly.GetType("AA.UI.WPF.COMMON.Program");
            MethodInfo main = program.GetMethod("Main");
            main.Invoke(null, null);            
        }
        public static Login AccessLogin()
        {
            return Login.Instance;
        }
    }
}
```

and **Login**

```
using System;
using AA.UI.WPF.COMMON;

namespace AA.UI.WPF.WND
{
    public partial class Login 
    {
        internal static Login Instance => _instance ?? (_instance = new Login());
        private static Login _instance = null;
        public Login()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            if (_instance == null) _instance = this;
        }
        internal void ShowMessage(string msg)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(msg);
        }
    }
```

**update**

it's work fine if I don't use reflection.

before the edit, I asked how can I can access a method outside of dynamically compiled c# code, I'm satisfied by @BionicCode answers. thank him. see comments.

your answer is completely true. since you post the first answer I have said you this is true. I use dynamic type as you said.

but now the last thing, I can't access the private or internal method, `RuntimeBinderException: 'AA.UI.WPF.WND.Login.ShowMessage(string)' is inaccessible due to its protection level`. I think it's normal

**goal**

my goal is to inject some code as a string and run these like other normal code without reflection because it's too complicated and access to other classes, types, etc... inside current namespace FD.UI.WPF. if you know another easier way, please provide.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Like always, it would be very interesting to know the error message you get. I assume you are getting a compiler error?

But generally you should be able to execute methods from other assemblies.

Based on your code, you have to add the proper references to the `CompilerParameters`, which is the assembly that contains the `CompileCSCAtRuntime` type you wish to reference e.g., `AA.UI.WPF.COMMON.dll` (I don't know the real assembly name at this point):

```
CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters();
parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll"); 
parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Windows.dll");
parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("AA.UI.WPF.COMMON.dll");
```

Now you can use the following code (note the added `using` import):

```
string code = @"
      using System;
      using System.Windows;
      using AA.UI.WPF.COMMON;

      namespace AA.UI.WPF.COMMON
      {
        public class Program
        {
          public static void Main()
          {
            CompileCSCAtRuntime.ShowMessage(""hello"");
          }
        }
      }";
```

---

To add more flexibility, you have to dynamically load the assembly that contains the type and then execute the method using `MethodInfo` (reflection). This way you don't need to add any assembly references or `using` imports to the compiled code:

```
string code = @"
      using System;
      using System.Windows;
      using System.Reflection;

      namespace AA.UI.WPF.COMMON
      {
        public class Program
        {
          public static void Main()
          {
            var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(@""Path_To_Assembly"");
            Type type = assembly.GetType(""AA.UI.WPF.COMMON.CompileCSCAtRuntime"");
            MethodInfo method = type.GetMethod(""ShowMessage"");
            method.Invoke(null, new[] { ""hello"" });
          }
        }
      }";
```

You can use this snippet to output or log compiler errors:

```
CompilerResults results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, code);
if (results.Errors.Count > 0)
{
  MessageBox.Show(
    results.Errors
      .Cast<CompilerError>()
      .Select(error => error.ErrorText)
      .Aggregate((result, currentValue) => result += $";{Environment.NewLine}{currentValue}"));
}
```

---

### Addressing your update

Now, that the context has changed, you have to adopt your code to this new scenario. First of all `dynamic` is not required here. You can use `var` or `object` instead, which has *significantly* less overhead (even when considering boxing scenarios). When using reflection, you should try to be as efficient as possible, because reflection itself is already expensive.

You are currently invoking `Login.ShowMessage` using the *instance* that was returned by

```
dynamic L = AccessLogin.Invoke(null, null);
L.ShowMessage(""hi"");
```

When using the *instance*, you are bound to the compiled access rules, which say that `Login.ShowMessage` is `internal` (you know that `internal` restricts access to assembly scope).
Since your dynamically compiled code is compiled into a new dynamic assembly, the caller's scope (the dynamic code) does no longer satisfy this access constraint.

To get around this visibility constraints, you have to access and invoke non-public members using reflection. To get the `MemberInfo` of any non-public member you always have to specify the appropriate `BindingFlags` combinations:

```
string code = @"
        using System;
        using System.Windows;
        using System.Reflection;
        namespace AA.UI.WPF.COMMON
        {
          public class Program
          {
            public static void Main()
            {
              var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(@""Path_To_Assembly"");
              Type compileCSCAtRuntimeType = assembly.GetType(""AA.UI.WPF.COMMON.CompileCSCAtRuntime"");
              MethodInfo accessLoginMethod = compileCSCAtRuntimeType.GetMethod(""AccessLogin"");

              object resultInstance = accessLoginMethod.Invoke(null, null);
              Type resultType = resultInstance.GetType();
              MethodInfo resultMethod = resultType.GetMethod(""ShowMessage"", 
                BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static);
              resultMethod.Invoke(resultInstance, new [] { ""hi"" });
            }
          }
        }";
```

Comment: the last code you provided helped me,
the problem is I want to behave with external code like other internal code inside of the current namespace. for now, I can access to ShowMessage() method but the goal is access to ShowMessage() when it is a PRIVATE or internal method.
I want to inject some code into my application remotely, so I should access my other methods. what is your suggestion?

Comment: First I realized some mistake in my code. The referenced type should be `CompileCSCAtRuntime` and not `Program`:  `assembly.GetType("AA.UI.WPF.COMMON.CompileCSCAtRuntime");`. You also need to import the Reflection namespace: `using System.Reflection;`. I am not sure if I understand you right. Since you are using reflection, you have access to _any_ type, whether it is public, static or private. You only need to know which type you want. You can use `Assembly.GetTypes` to enumerate all types declared in an assembly.

Comment: I have added a version that fixes your initial problem withou using reflection in the compiled code.

Comment: If you want to load assemblies that are e.g. added to a folder at runtime, you can use the [Managed Extensibility Framework (MEF)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/mef/) which is part of .NET. It's simple to use. I don't know if this is your intend (to load assemblies dynamically and execute methods of certain types.

Comment: I guess you misunderstand some part of the question. I try to invoke `Main()` method, not `ShowMessage()`
the `Main()` method is the method that consists of many methods one of them is `ShowMessage()`
so `assembly.GetType("AA.UI.WPF.COMMON.CompileCSCAtRuntime");` will not help. it should be `assembly.GetType("AA.UI.WPF.COMMON.Program");` .I'm reviewing your answer

Comment: Hmm. You have a class `CompileCSCAtRuntime` that defines a static `ShowMessage`. Then you compile a class `Programm` at runtime and execute a method of this type. So the fact that this method `Main()` references an external member `ShowMessage` of `CompileCSCAtRuntime` is of no interest? You simply want to compile a class at runtime and invoke its method, is that correct? And your problem now is to find a generic way to invoke any method of the compiled class you need?

Comment: You should know that your current code works if you fix the dependency issues (because `Propgram` references an external assembly, the one that contains `CompileCSCAtRuntime.ShowMessage`. I fixed this in my answer. Please help me to understand your problem. Otherwise I'm not able to help. I previously understood your goal would be to access members of external assemblies from your runtime compiled types.

Comment: You asked _"my question is how can I access a method outside of dynamically compiled c# code. for example a method inside of AA.UI.WPF.WND namespace."_ And I think I have provided the answer. But it feels like you are not satisfied.

Comment: The first solution was to add a reference to the `CompilerParameters` e.g. `parameters..ReferencedAssemblies.Add("AA.UI.WPF.WND.dll");` (basically the assembly name of the assembly that contains the type - can be an _.exe_ or _.dll_ assembly) and then add the corresponding import to the dynamic type `using AA.UI.WPF.WND`. Or the second solution I've provided was to use reflection inside the dynamic type. The second solution would allow to access even `private` or `internal` types (this is what I understood from your first comment is what you need).

Comment: the question updated, dynamic type helped me. is there anything?

Comment: many years ago when I wanted to be hired in a company and work with .net,  I realized I don't know anything about .net. now I feel I have that feeling again. thank you, you solved my problem very clear.
also, I'm wondering why others, rating negatively to my question? while they didn't share their knowledge.

Comment: I am happy that I could help you. Don't be too harsh. I wouldn't say _"I don't know anything"_. .NET is a huge ecosystem with lots of frameworks and libraries. There exist multiple ways to achieve a goal, depending on e.g. framework version etc. I would rather say: _"I don't know everything"_. As you move along, problems you need to solve get more complex. So are their solutions. That's why some say problems are the chance to learn and improve. Now you'v added something more to your repertoire.

Comment: You are absolutely right. They should have make down voting more useful by forcing the voter to leave a comment. It's hard to improve if you don't know the wrong. To know the wrong doesn't help to improve, if nobody tells you the right. It's worth nothing. In a worst case the downvote itself is wrong or based on misconception or the voter's own misunderstanding. It would degrade an answer or question without any good or valid reason. Apparently, being constructive is not easy and not natural to people. You know I got a downvote myself don't knowing the reason too. I gave you an up.

Answer (score -1):

Just like you referenced other assemblies, you have to create and reference your own assembly.

- Create another C# project, `AssemblyOfMessageHelper`, with a new class, for example `MessageHelper`, containing `ShowMessage`.
- Then in your dynamically compiled code, call `MessageHelper.ShowMessage`.
- Make sure it has the `using NamespaceOfMessageHelper;` and
- You reference the assembly `parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("AssemblyOfMessageHelper.dll");`.
- Keep in mind that the assembly needs to be in a folder where it can be found, because the `System.*` assemblies are found in GAC (.NET framework) or in the appropriate SDK framework location (.NET core), and both of those will not have your `AssemblyOfMessageHelper.dll`.

**UPDATE**: as others have pointed out, you can simplify this further by referencing your own assembly: `parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("MainProject.exe");` However, I still maintain that creating a separate assembly is the preferred way to go.

Comment: the output of my project is a .exe file, not .dll. so it does not work. On the other hand, I want to access all methods inside of AA.UI.WPF namespace. if you can please write a quick snippet code.

Comment: The output of the existing project is .exe, but you create **another** project which is a DLL.

Comment: is there any way to access the existing methods in .exe project? instead of creating a new .dll file? @mr-ta

Comment: There is no need to create an additional assembly. You can add the current assembly.

Comment: @KrisVandermotten yes, right. I have added .exe file and it worked;